# Call multiple stored procedures within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure that calls multiple other stored procedures and saves the output parameters into variables as each stored procedure's output is the input parameters for the next one.

My code looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sa.sp_step0(inout name text)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE 

id text;
run text;
tables_step2 text[];
tables_step3 text[];
tables_step4 text[];
table_step5 text;

BEGIN

    
    call sa.sp_step1(model_name) insert into id,run;
    call sa.sp_step2(id,run) insert into id,run,tables_step2;
    call sa.sp_step3(id,run,tables_step2) insert into id,run,tables_step3;
    call sa.sp_step4(id,run,tables_step3) insert into id,run,tables_step4;
    call sa.sp_step5(id,run,tables_step4) insert into id,run,tables_step5;

    return;
end
$$;
```

I get the following error:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "insert"¶

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as though you're using the syntax of some other database product.

To do what you're trying to do in PostgreSQL, you'd need to [declare your procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createprocedure.html) something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_step1(IN model_name TEXT, INOUT id TEXT, INOUT run TEXT)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS...
```

and then [call your procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-call.html) as

```
call sa.sp_step1(model_name, id, run);
call sa.sp_step2(id, run, tables_step2);
call sa.sp_step3(id, run, tables_step2, tables_step3);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Man I love it when I figure out my own errors and help someone else out there in the www....

basically, if you want to save the outputs of a stored procedure into a variable, you would do the following:

```
execute ('sa.sp_step1(''' || model_name|| ''')') into id,run;
```